# Doubt in the framing of a question on Venn diagram

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In a group of $265$ people, $200$ like singing, $110$ like dancing and $55$ like painting. If $60$ people like both singing and dancing, $30$ like both singing and painting and $10$ like all the three activities, then the number of people who like only dancing and painting are?

Now I know that this question has been asked before. But the problem I am facing is in the framing of the question. In all the solutions that I have seen, in all of them, we are considering that all these $265$ people like some activity.

My question is why isn't it possible that out of $265$ people, some of them don't like any of the three activities?

Comment: Technically you are correct, it can be such that someone likes none of the activities. But then the question is unanswerable.

Comment: It sure is possible.

Comment: If nobody likes any of the activities or you do not make the assumption that everyone likes at least one activity, we are simply faced with a different mathematical problem.  So while it is possible in the real world, that is just not the assumption we are making in the problem.

Comment: You are correct, and the question is very poorly written: that assumption absolutely should be made explicit. The only reason that I would guess that it was being made here is that the question cannot be answered without information beyond what is explicitly given and that is the most likely extra datum.

Comment: Many well-posed questions involving sets and Venn diagrams make these conditions explicit.